# DatePicker's value is empty but still start from last pick out in latest kendo version

Tags: html, datepicker, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo MVVM to bind a datepicker value.
If I use datepicker to pick out a date (not today),
and then use MVVM to set value to empty and I open the datepicker again, it will start from the date you last pick out!

Here's the code I'm using:

HTML:

```html
<input type="text" data-role="datepicker" data-bind="value: date" />
<button data-bind="click: clear">clear</button>
```

SCRIPT:

```js
kendo.init($("*"));
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    date: "",
    clear: function () {
        this.set("date", "");
    }
});
kendo.bind($("*"), viewModel);​
```

How can I let the datepicker always start from today if its value is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just assign the current date to 'date' of your view-model once clear() is called?

```
var today = new Date();
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
   date: today,
   clear: function () {
       this.set("date", today);
   }
});
```